# How can I get my Arduino Duemilanove to work with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, arduino

I am having trouble getting my Arduino Duemilanove (w/ ATmega328) to work under Windows 7 Professional (64 bit).

I have the Arduino 1.04 software in Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10 (64 bit) on the same machine (dual booting).

I have no issues connecting in Ubuntu but can't get windows to connect to it.
I have already tried installing the included FTDI drivers.
I have been able to successfully connect my Arduino Uno while in Windows 7.

I am hoping this is user error or a driver issue. What should I try next? or is there a known solution?

- For the time being I've been connecting to it from Ubuntu but would like to be able to use it with some Windows programs in the future.

Comment: I'm running Win7 Pro and connecting to a couple of Freeduinos (Duemilanove clones) so its definitely doable. When the Due is plugged in and powered on does it appear in your Device Manager as a COM Port?

Comment: Same here, I have a Duemilanove working fine under Windows 7 64 bit. I don't recall whether I had to do something specific, but you might want to go through the installation documentation for any required software installation or configuration prerequisites.

Comment: Does it appear in the Device Manager under USB devices?

Comment: This site is for electrical engineering.